# Not getting tweets using FHSTwitterEngine

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, tweets, fhs-twitter-engine

I am using latest Library of FHSTwitterEngine. I want to fetch recent 20 tweets from the all the users.

I am trying to do this way.

```
self.engine = [[FHSTwitterEngine alloc] init];
[self.engine permanentlySetConsumerKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY andSecret:TWITTER_SECRET_KEY];

id res = [self.engine searchTweetsWithQuery: @"cricket" count:10 resultType:FHSTwitterEngineResultTypeRecent unil:[NSDate date] sinceID:@"1920030" maxID:@"1930030"];

NSLog(@"%@",res);
```

When I do this, I am getting this response.

```
Error Domain=FHSErrorDomain Code=401 "You are not authorized via OAuth" UserInfo=0xe5cbce0 {url=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json, parameters={
    count = 10;
    "include_entities" = false;
    "max_id" = 1930030;
    q = cricket;
    "result_type" = recent;
    "since_id" = 1920030;
    until = "2014-01-22";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=You are not authorized via OAuth}
```

Am I missing something in this?

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

Append

```
[[self.engine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];
[[self.engine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];
```

Comment: but I want only public tweets and I don't have user token. Can i use loadAccessToken()